# How to connect a factory with a service that take too much time?

Tags: angularjs

We have to retrieve some information from an API that requier a hash that we calculate in client side, but take quite time on finishing. We haven't been able to sync with the angular cycle, the most we can do, was to set a timeout to calculate the hash, but although we now get the hash and get the information, that breaks the angular cycle and we can use it.

We are pretty new with angular (1.0.7) and we know that we missing something, any help on this matter will be appriaceted

**Update** a code omitting some obvious parts, I think, please let me know if isnt in that way.

https://code.google.com/p/javascript-bcrypt/ and dependencies are properly loaded, so we created a service that calculate the hash (one more thing, this is needed that the hash is calculated once only)

```
.service('hashSrv', function(SALT, $q, $timeout) {
    var bcrypt, token = '', secure = '', deferred = $q.defer();

    bcrypt = new bCrypt();
    token = Base64.encode("Sometoken");

    return {
        generate: function() {
            bcrypt.hashpw(token, SALT, function(hash) {
              secure = hash;
            });  
        },
        getSecure: function() {
            return secure;
        },
        getToken: function() {
            return token;
        },
        getData: function() {
            return {
                'token': token,
                'secure': secure
            }
        }
    }
})
```

Here is our factory resource:

```
.factory('InfoSrv', function ($http, RESOURCE_URL, HashSrv, $timeout) {
    return $timeout( function() {
        $http({method: 'GET', url: 'RESOURCE_URL?token=' + HashSrv.getToken() + '&secure=' + HashSrv.getSecure()})
        .success(function(response, data, status, headers, config) {
            //Here we have the correct response
        })
        .error(function(response, data, status, headers, config) {
            //Check if something bad happens
        });
    }, 200);
})
```

And finally, we aare trying to use it in our controller

```
.controller('DataCtrl',
    ['$scope', 'InfoSrv', 
    function ($scope, InfoSrv) {
        $scope.user.basicInformation = $scope.getBasicInfo();
        //Here we can get the info :(
    }
])
```

Comment: What is the logic to calculate hash? It sounds like a pretty quick procedure.

Comment: We are using https://code.google.com/p/javascript-bcrypt/

Comment: Should post some of your angular code where you are calling the crypt function so we can help you better. But it's most likely that you need to call $scope.$apply(); to let angular know about any updates you've calculated outside of angular's digest cycle.

Comment: ok, let me take a moment to simplified a bit and then I'll update the question.

Answer (score 1):

The $timeout service returns a promise, and the value that the promise is resolved with is whatever is returned within the function passed to $timeout. In your case you aren't returning anything inside of $timeout.

I'm not sure why you need the $timeout either. You can just return the $http() which will also return the promise. Then move your success,error methods out of the service.

Comment: Because the hash take some time in being calculated

Answer (score 0):

In the hashSrv, `generate()` should return a deferred promise

```
generate: function() {
        bcrypt.hashpw(token, SALT, function(hash) {
            secure = hash;
            deferred.resolve(hash);
        });  
        return deferred.promise;
}
```

The factory should return a `promise` like this:

```
.factory('InfoSrv', function ($http, RESOURCE_URL, HashSrv, $timeout) {
    return {
        getBasicInfo: function () {
            var promise = $http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: 'RESOURCE_URL?token=' + HashSrv.getToken() + '&secure=' + HashSrv.getSecure()
            }).success(function (response, data, status, headers, config) {
                return data;
            }).error(function (response, data, status, headers, config) {
                //Check if something bad happens
            });
            return promise;
        };
    }
});
```

And you can consume the service like this in your controller:

```
.controller('DataCtrl', ['$scope', 'InfoSrv', 'hashSrv', function ($scope, InfoSrv, hashSrv) {
    hashSrv.generate().then(function (hash) {
        InfoSrv.getBasicInfo().then(function (data) {
            $scope.user.basicInformation = data;
        })
    })
}])
```

Comment: Hi here is the thing, the request is execute before we get the hash :(

Comment: @raulricardo21 I updated the generate() and the controller. I haven't test the code, you should be able to do something similar like this.

Comment: Hi @sza, The request is not executed but the hash is calculated

Comment: @raulricardo21 dump the log of both success and error. You should be able to debug it yourself.

Comment: No, I couldn't find the way... I'm debbugging and the only I can think is if maybe is the angular version